# What's the tag [project] for?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I was reading a question and noticed it was tagged with [project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project). Looking further I see 65 questions tagged with it, 28 unanswered. There's no description for this tag, but it seems to be used mainly for asking about *blender Projects* and *projecting stuff onto models* (texture, geometry, etc).

Shall we split this tag into 2, perhaps [blender-project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-project) and [projection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection) or [projecting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projecting) to avoid confusion? (or retag it to other existing, more popular tags I might not be aware of)

Comment: I'd encourage you to post your proposed solution for the tags as an answer so other people can vote what to do with them.

Comment: there seem to be some developements in the area of ]project management](https://developer.blender.org/D16288) underway, answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like one of those tags that "crept in" and discretely stayed around despite being unwanted.

As it stands I agree with your assessment, its meaning is unclear as you stated.

Both of your proposed uses seem unwanted to me as well, those sound like "meta-tags" they don't really tell you anything about the question and aren't very useful for categorization either.

Technically speaking, virtually all questions here are in some form about "Blender-Projects", and the tag isn't really elucidative about the question content.

I'd reserve this tag for some later time when Blender actually has some form of "Project Management" and a concrete concept of what an actual "Project" really is. In the stricter sense of a collection of related files, folders or content all pertaining to some common final finished product.

The use of "Project" as verb "to project" something over a surface seems too specific and abstract to warrant a dedicated tag. It really doesn't help categorize a question in any meaningful way and should not exist. Mentioning the word in the body of the question should suffice for searching purposes.

I'd vote for removing the tag entirely, it doesn't seem helpful in any way.

Once again this seems like a community decision, so I'd encourage anyone else to post their suggestions as questions and let the voting decide the outcome.

As of 10 October 2022 there seems to be the first steps towards project management in Blender with the introduction of the concept of a "Blender Project" in the task [Basic Blender Project Support (experimental feature)](https://developer.blender.org/D16288), for which this tag would seem most adequate, maybe in the form of [project-management](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) or [project-manager](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-manager) depending on how the feature ends up implemented.

Comment: I agree with your answer, so I won't post mine with tag suggestions as you asked - perhaps someone more knowledgeable can come up with more relevant tags if they think there would be any.

Comment: @Luciano If you still want to be involved later on, and we do decide eliminating the tag is the way to go, then you can help remove the tag entirely by retagging existing questions with something else more fitting, or just deleting the tag all together.

Comment: sure, let me know whenever that happens